# Qt Designer проблема со scrollBar, который не хочет нормально отображаться, когда использую StyleSheet

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside2, qss, qscrollbar

Я использую *PySide2*, хотя и в *PyQt5* такая же проблема.

Ссылка, откуда я брал раскраску скролла (Если вдруг поможет):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttBjf4bMDXY&t=627s&ab_channel=Wanderson

Когда я запускаю `test.ui`* в *QT Designer*, проблема со скролом в `stylesheet` нет нигде, а когда я запускаю через `main.py`, то в `TextEdit` и `PlainTextEdit` не отображается нормально `scrollbar` (На картинке будет видно):

[image]

Как решить эту проблему?

---

Вот код каждого файла:

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtLocation
from PySide2.QtGui import QClipboard
import PySide2.QtWidgets
import PySide2.QtCore
from windowtest import Ui_Dialog
class main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super(main, self). __init__()
        self.windowtest = Ui_Dialog()
        self.windowtest.setupUi(self)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = main()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
#pyside2-uic test.ui -o windowtest.py
```

**test.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>371</width>
    <height>355</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: #1a1a26;</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>50</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>111</width>
     <height>231</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QTextEdit{
    background-color: #22222e;
    border: 3px solid #7611ed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font: 87 8pt &quot;Segoe UI Black&quot;;
}
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: none;
    background: #2d2d44;
    width: 14px;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
 }

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {   
    background-color: #5e00cc;
    min-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover { 
    background-color: #9900ff;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:pressed {   
    background-color: #5100a0;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: #3b3b5a;
    height: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover {   
    background-color: #9900ff;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:pressed { 
    background-color: #5100a0;
}


QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: #3b3b5a;
    height: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover {   
    background-color: #ff9900;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:pressed { 
    background-color: #ba7000;
}

QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
    
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}</string>
   </property>
   <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="html">
    <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'Segoe UI Black'; font-size:8pt; font-weight:80; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="plainTextEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>170</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>111</width>
     <height>231</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QPlainTextEdit{
    background-color: #22222e;
    border: 3px solid #7611ed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font: 87 8pt &quot;Segoe UI Black&quot;;
}
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: none;
    background: #2d2d44;
    width: 14px;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
 }

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {   
    background-color: #5e00cc;
    min-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover { 
    background-color: #9900ff;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:pressed {   
    background-color: #5100a0;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: #3b3b5a;
    height: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover {   
    background-color: #9900ff;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:pressed { 
    background-color: #5100a0;
}


QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: #3b3b5a;
    height: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover {   
    background-color: #ff9900;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:pressed { 
    background-color: #ba7000;
}

QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
    
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}</string>
   </property>
   <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="plainText">
    <string>1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QScrollBar" name="verticalScrollBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>300</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>20</width>
     <height>231</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: none;
    background: #2d2d44;
    width: 14px;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
 }

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {   
    background-color: #5e00cc;
    min-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover { 
    background-color: #9900ff;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:pressed {   
    background-color: #5100a0;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: #3b3b5a;
    height: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover {   
    background-color: #9900ff;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:pressed { 
    background-color: #5100a0;
}


QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: #3b3b5a;
    height: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover {   
    background-color: #ff9900;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:pressed { 
    background-color: #ba7000;
}

QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
    
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}</string>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

После я перевёл `test.ui` в `windowtest.py` с помощью `pyside2`, командой в консоли:

**`pyside2-uic test.ui -o windowtest.py`**

Сам код **windowtest.py**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        if not Dialog.objectName():
            Dialog.setObjectName(u"Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(371, 355)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: #1a1a26;")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(u"textEdit")
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QRect(50, 70, 111, 231))
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet(u"QTextEdit{\n"
"   background-color: #22222e;\n"
"   border: 3px solid #7611ed;\n"
"   border-radius: 10px;\n"
"   color: #f5f5f5;\n"
"   font: 87 8pt \"Segoe UI Black\";\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar:vertical {\n"
"   border: none;\n"
"    background: #2d2d44;\n"
"    width: 14px;\n"
"    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;\n"
"   border-radius: 0px;\n"
" }\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical {  \n"
"   background-color: #5e00cc;\n"
"   min-height: 30px;\n"
"   border-radius: 7px;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover {    \n"
"   background-color: #9900ff;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical:pressed {  \n"
"   background-color: #5100a0;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {\n"
"   border: none;\n"
"   background-color: #3b3b5a;\n"
"   height: 15px;\n"
"   border-top-left-radius: 7px;\n"
"   border-top-right-radius: 7px;\n"
"   subcontrol-position: top;\n"
"   subcontrol-origin: margin;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover {  \n"
"   background-color: #9900ff;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:pressed {    \n"
"   background-color: #5100a0;\n"
"}\n"
""
                        "\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {\n"
"   border: none;\n"
"   background-color: #3b3b5a;\n"
"   height: 15px;\n"
"   border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;\n"
"   border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;\n"
"   subcontrol-position: bottom;\n"
"   subcontrol-origin: margin;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover {  \n"
"   background-color: #ff9900;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:pressed {    \n"
"   background-color: #ba7000;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {\n"
"   background: none;\n"
"   \n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {\n"
"   background: none;\n"
"}")
        self.textEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.textEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName(u"plainTextEdit")
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QRect(170, 70, 111, 231))
        self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet(u"QPlainTextEdit{\n"
"   background-color: #22222e;\n"
"   border: 3px solid #7611ed;\n"
"   border-radius: 10px;\n"
"   color: #f5f5f5;\n"
"   font: 87 8pt \"Segoe UI Black\";\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar:vertical {\n"
"   border: none;\n"
"    background: #2d2d44;\n"
"    width: 14px;\n"
"    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;\n"
"   border-radius: 0px;\n"
" }\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical {  \n"
"   background-color: #5e00cc;\n"
"   min-height: 30px;\n"
"   border-radius: 7px;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover {    \n"
"   background-color: #9900ff;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical:pressed {  \n"
"   background-color: #5100a0;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {\n"
"   border: none;\n"
"   background-color: #3b3b5a;\n"
"   height: 15px;\n"
"   border-top-left-radius: 7px;\n"
"   border-top-right-radius: 7px;\n"
"   subcontrol-position: top;\n"
"   subcontrol-origin: margin;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover {  \n"
"   background-color: #9900ff;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:pressed {    \n"
"   background-color: #5100a0;\n"
""
                        "}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {\n"
"   border: none;\n"
"   background-color: #3b3b5a;\n"
"   height: 15px;\n"
"   border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;\n"
"   border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;\n"
"   subcontrol-position: bottom;\n"
"   subcontrol-origin: margin;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover {  \n"
"   background-color: #ff9900;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:pressed {    \n"
"   background-color: #ba7000;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {\n"
"   background: none;\n"
"   \n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {\n"
"   background: none;\n"
"}")
        self.plainTextEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.plainTextEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.verticalScrollBar = QScrollBar(Dialog)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setObjectName(u"verticalScrollBar")
        self.verticalScrollBar.setGeometry(QRect(300, 70, 20, 231))
        self.verticalScrollBar.setStyleSheet(u"QScrollBar:vertical {\n"
"   border: none;\n"
"    background: #2d2d44;\n"
"    width: 14px;\n"
"    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;\n"
"   border-radius: 0px;\n"
" }\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical {  \n"
"   background-color: #5e00cc;\n"
"   min-height: 30px;\n"
"   border-radius: 7px;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover {    \n"
"   background-color: #9900ff;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical:pressed {  \n"
"   background-color: #5100a0;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {\n"
"   border: none;\n"
"   background-color: #3b3b5a;\n"
"   height: 15px;\n"
"   border-top-left-radius: 7px;\n"
"   border-top-right-radius: 7px;\n"
"   subcontrol-position: top;\n"
"   subcontrol-origin: margin;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover {  \n"
"   background-color: #9900ff;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:pressed {    \n"
"   background-color: #5100a0;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {\n"
"   border: none;\n"
"   background-color: #3b3b5a;\n"
"   height: 15px;\n"
"   border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;\n"
"   border-bottom-"
                        "right-radius: 7px;\n"
"   subcontrol-position: bottom;\n"
"   subcontrol-origin: margin;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover {  \n"
"   background-color: #ff9900;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:pressed {    \n"
"   background-color: #ba7000;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {\n"
"   background: none;\n"
"   \n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {\n"
"   background: none;\n"
"}")
        self.verticalScrollBar.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"Dialog", None))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:'Segoe UI Black'; font-size:8pt; font-weight:80; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100</p></body></html>", None))
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100", None))
```

Сказали сделать программе стиль `'Fusion'`, но это всё ещё не тот результат, который нужен:

[image]

Comment: объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать? Зачем вам `verticalScrollBar`, который вы подписали на изображении как: "А вот так должно". `QTextEdit` и `QPlainTextEdit` уже имеют `QScrollBar`.

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы у меня был скроллбар на который применён stylesheet, а он почему-то не работает так, как на "А вот так должно"

Comment: стиль программы может не "пропускать", сделайте программе стиль "Fusion"

Comment: т.е. `verticalScrollBar` вам совсем не нужен и вы его показали как образец, который надо сделать в других виджетах или вы хотите/будите его (`verticalScrollBar`) использовать?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы он постоянно был активен и был "раскрашен", как самая правая (Я новичок в этом, поэтому может не совсем понятно описал) Используется в TextEdit, если потребуется уточнения; но всё же, желательно бы, чтобы во всех подобных работал

Comment: @Pavel Gridin, сделал, как вы сказали, но результат всё ещё не тот (В вопросе прикрепил картинку)

Comment: Я не понимаю честно говоря что происходит, когда я открываю в своём дизайнере test.ui он как на первой картинке, но если я открою редактор стиля для одного из редакторов и просто нажму [Apply], то скроллбар становится фиолетовый

Comment: @Pavel Gridin тоже самое, в Qt Designer этот файл нормально открывается, но когда просто запускаешь, то почему-то скроллбар не становиться фиолетовым...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не надо писать таблицу стилей для `QScrollBar` в каждом виджете. Вставьте ее **`один`** раз в виджет на основе которого вы создавали окно (`QDialog`).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**q1300206_text.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>371</width>
    <height>355</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">QDialog {
background-color: #1a1a26;
 }
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: none;
    background: #2d2d44;
    width: 14px;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
 }

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {   
    background-color: #5e00cc;
    min-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover { 
    background-color: #9900ff;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical:pressed {   
    background-color: #5100a0;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: #3b3b5a;
    height: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover {   
    background-color: #9900ff;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:pressed { 
    background-color: #5100a0;
}


QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: #3b3b5a;
    height: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover {   
    background-color: #ff9900;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:pressed { 
    background-color: #ba7000;
}

QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
    
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>50</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>111</width>
     <height>231</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QTextEdit{
    background-color: #22222e;
    border: 3px solid #7611ed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font: 87 8pt &quot;Segoe UI Black&quot;;
}
</string>
   </property>
   <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="html">
    <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'Segoe UI Black'; font-size:8pt; font-weight:80; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;&gt;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPlainTextEdit" name="plainTextEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>170</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>111</width>
     <height>231</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QPlainTextEdit{
    background-color: #22222e;
    border: 3px solid #7611ed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    font: 87 8pt &quot;Segoe UI Black&quot;;
}
</string>
   </property>
   <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="plainText">
    <string>1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QScrollBar" name="verticalScrollBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>300</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>20</width>
     <height>231</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true"/>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

**q1300206_text_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(371, 355)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("QDialog {\n"
"background-color: #1a1a26;\n"
" }\n"
"QScrollBar:vertical {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background: #2d2d44;\n"
"    width: 14px;\n"
"    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
" }\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical {   \n"
"    background-color: #5e00cc;\n"
"    min-height: 30px;\n"
"    border-radius: 7px;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover { \n"
"    background-color: #9900ff;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::handle:vertical:pressed {   \n"
"    background-color: #5100a0;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background-color: #3b3b5a;\n"
"    height: 15px;\n"
"    border-top-left-radius: 7px;\n"
"    border-top-right-radius: 7px;\n"
"    subcontrol-position: top;\n"
"    subcontrol-origin: margin;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover {   \n"
"    background-color: #9900ff;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:pressed { \n"
"    background-color: #5100a0;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    background-color: #3b3b5a;\n"
"    height: 15px;\n"
"    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;\n"
"    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;\n"
"    subcontrol-position: bottom;\n"
"    subcontrol-origin: margin;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover {   \n"
"    background-color: #ff9900;\n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:pressed { \n"
"    background-color: #ba7000;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"    \n"
"}\n"
"QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {\n"
"    background: none;\n"
"}")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 70, 111, 231))
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit{\n"
"    background-color: #22222e;\n"
"    border: 3px solid #7611ed;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    color: #f5f5f5;\n"
"    font: 87 8pt \"Segoe UI Black\";\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.textEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.textEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 70, 111, 231))
        self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet("QPlainTextEdit{\n"
"    background-color: #22222e;\n"
"    border: 3px solid #7611ed;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    color: #f5f5f5;\n"
"    font: 87 8pt \"Segoe UI Black\";\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.plainTextEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.plainTextEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.verticalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(Dialog)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 70, 20, 231))
        self.verticalScrollBar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.verticalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Segoe UI Black\'; font-size:8pt; font-weight:80; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100</p></body></html>"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(_translate("Dialog", "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100"))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с точки зрения оптимальности да, вы правы, но поведение стилей всё равно не понятно